# How to change the color of a specific word in a message?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I've working on an assignment with the Raspberry Pi. I want to change the color of a word in a string or message in an if statement.
I tried doing this.
[image]

It came up with an error saying "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects". Does anyone know how to do what I'm trying to do?
Thanks

Comment: What makes you think this is possible?  Have you found a command to set the text colour?  Surely setting a colour depends on the medium displaying the text?

Comment: I'm making it display the text on a raspberry pi. To change the text colour, you need to write text_colour = (the variable with the rgb values). I just don't know how to change the colour of a word out of a sentence.

Comment: Please add the error message to your question.

Comment: Ah, let me see.  So you want to change colour of Rpi SenseHat LED matrix message.   The colour setting part of your program is OK.  What causes the problem is you try to concatenate a string to a tuple.   In the first IF statement, "It is time for" is a string, but "(a, red)" is not a string.  The API to change colour of a dot of the matrix is the API: set_pixels: Sense Hat doc's API set_pixels
https://pythonhosted.org/sense-hat/api/. / to continue, ...

Comment: For your assignment, there are two functions you can use: (1) set_pixels: to set ALL 64 pixels in the matrix in one go. Example: sense.set_pixels(question_mark) to display the question mark in the LED matrix.  Of course you can display the letter "H" instead of a question mark.  (2) set_pixel (no "s" at the end) to set ONLY ONE of the 64 pixels.  It is this set only one pixel that you can use to individual pixel's colour.  / to continue, ...

Comment: To summarize, you can (1) use first command to display one letter of 64 pixels, but you need to decide what are the colour of each pixel before hand, and "build" the letter, or (2) You display the letter first, then use the second command to change the colour pixel by pixel, one pixel at a time. / to continue, ...

Comment: You said that 'a' is not a string but I've also written a="Break"

Comment: If your teacher's assignment is open ended, you can experiment with both methods, then write one function, with many parameters, including (1) a list of characters as the message string, (2) a matrix of 8 x 8 elements, each of which is for the colour of each pixel of the character, / to continue, ...

Comment: I am just suggesting one of many ways you can explore, of course you can think of better ways.  Have a nice assignment and good luck. Cheers.

Comment: Some clarifications (1) in your statement [a = "xyz“], "xyz" is a string, but [a] is the name of a variable for the string, (2) a string can only be concatenate to another string, NOT a tuple, which is not a string type, therefore type error.  I know it is confusing, so you need to study more python to understand what I am talking about.  Nice python learning, bye.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll try to understand it a bit more

Comment: So how do I turn the tuple into a string?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead paste the text direct into the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the ANSI escape code:

```
"\033[1;32;40m Bright Green"
```

The above ANSI escape code will set the text colour to bright green. The format is:
\033[  Escape code, this is always the same
1 = Style, 1 for normal.
32 = Text colour, 32 for bright green.
40m = Background colour, 40 is for black.

You can get the color codes [here](http://ozzmaker.com/add-colour-to-text-in-python/)

Comment: I don't mean changing the colour of the text on python. I want to change the colour of the text the raspberry pi displays

Comment: Well, you could set the colors for the pixels individually

Comment: I could but I want to know if there is an easier way

Comment: @roger.dude You want to change the color of the output from the Python script you posted in your question, correct? This answer is *exactly* how you do it. In you definitions of `a="Break"` and `b="Work"`, just add these escape characters. For example, `a="\033[1;32;40m Break"` will make the Pi display "Break" in the output as bright green. Moreover, this is not a Pi-specific question, it is a general programming question.

Answer (score 1):

This question is unclear and not Pi specific (and this answer does not address the python coding errors).

The following python code fragment is an example of how to display coloured text on a console using ANSI escape codes. This works on ANY platform, it may or may not work on a SenseHat.

```
RED   = "\033[1;31m"
RESET = "\033[0;0m"

def pRed(s):
    print("%s%s%s" % (RED, s, RESET), file=sys.stderr)
def perr(l):
    pRed("%s - Error on line %d:" % (l, lineno))
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant for the question to be Pi specific and not Raspberry Pi Desktop.